# Is the square of operator norm smooth?

Tags: matrices, operator-norms

Is $A \mapsto \|A\|_{op}^2$ a smooth function? Specifically, is the space of matrices equipped with operator norm a 2-smooth Banach space?

Comment: Let $A_t=\text{diag}(1+t,1-t)$. Then $\|A_t\|=1+|t|$.